# Properties of area under $f$

Tags: calculus

If the area under $f$ (derivative) accumulates at a decreasing rate, would $F$ be decreasing as well? Or, would I be looking for concavity?

Also, if $f$ (derivative) is positive, then would the graph necessarily be positive as well? Or, should I be looking for increasing?

This is my Graph of derivative $f$ of function $F$:

[image]

Comment: are you saying F'(x) = f(x) or f'(x) = F(x)?

Comment: @okzoomer f'(x) = F(x)

Comment: If the area under the curve of the derivative is accumulating (regardless of rate), then the original function must be increasing.

Comment: @Bonnaduck thank you! So if the derivative is positive then must the original function be increasing?

Comment: Exactly (and that should make sense!). The derivative tells you slopes, so if the derivative is positive, then your function must have a positive slope.

Comment: @Bonnaduck Alright, thanks! If I may ask, why is it that if the derivative is accumulating at a decreasing rate, why is the original function increasing instead of decreasing?

Comment: If the derivative is accumulating at a decreasing rate, it would look something like the graph you posted, after the point $g$. As you go past $g$, the area under the curve is accumulating, but at a decreasing rate. Nonetheless, the derivative is still positive, so the original function is increasing.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the graph, I meant after you go past point $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f'(x)$ be the derivative of $f(x)$. For our purposes, assume $f'(x)$ is continuous. Note the column headers.

| $f'(x)$ | $f(x)$ |
| --- | --- |
| is positive | is increasing |
| is zero | has horizontal tangent line |
| is negative | is decreasing |
| is increasing | concaves up ($\cup$) |
| is decreasing | concaves down ($\cap$) |
| is horizontal | is changing at a constant rate and/or is a candidate for turning point |

You should investigate such relationships with $g'(x) = \cos x$, $g(x) = \sin x$, as well as $h'(x) = -\sin x$, $h(x) = \cos x$.

In your function, when $x < -3.9$, $f'(x)$ is negative, so $f(x)$ is

> decreasing.

When $x > -3.9$, $f'(x)$ is positive, so $f(x)$ is

> increasing.

That makes $x = -3.9$ on $f(x)$ a

> local minimum

because of the

> $\cup$ shape.

$f'(x)$ is increasing when $x < -3$, so $f(x)$

> concaves up.

Conversely, $f'(x)$ is decreasing when $x > -3$, so $f(x)$

> concaves down.

Is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x = -3$? What is that point called?

> $f'(-3) = 2$ so the derivative of $f(x)$ is 2 when $x = -3$. This is a turning point on $f(x)$ as $f'(x)$ changed from increasing to decreasing.